# At what point in the Activity Lifecycle does an ActivityMonitor fire?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have a test that is using an ActivityMonitor to wait for an activity to start, e.g.

```
// ins is an instance of the Instrumentation class.
Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor mon = new Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor((String)null, null, false);
ins.addMonitor(mon);
// do something that will start an activity
Activity a = ins.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(mon, msWaitTime);
```

At the point when waitForMonitorWithTimeout returns, what point in the activity lifecycle is the activity at, has it already been through create/start/resume etc, or is that still going on ? The docs just say that it returns the started activity, but with no indication of what state the activity is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but testing shows that the `waitForMonitorWithTimeout` call returns very early in the new activities lifecycle, as far as i can tell, just after onCreate returns.